# Can not reach Vault by HTTP API in Docker on MacOS

Tags: docker

Hello I'm trying to setup Vault in Docker on MacOS. But ever after successful installing I can't reach it through HTTP API (https://www.vaultproject.io/intro/getting-started/apis.html).

Dockerfile:

```
FROM    centos:centos6

ENV VAULT_VERSION=0.3.0
ENV VAULT_SHA256=30b8953e98059d1e8d97f6a164aa574a346a58caf9c5c74a911056f42fbef4d5
RUN yum install -y wget unzip
RUN \
  wget http://dl.bintray.com/mitchellh/vault/vault_${VAULT_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip &&\
  echo "${VAULT_SHA256}  vault_${VAULT_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip" | sha256sum -c - &&\
  unzip vault_${VAULT_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip &&\
  rm vault_${VAULT_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip &&\
  mv vault /usr/bin

EXPOSE 8200

ENTRYPOINT ["vault"]
CMD ["server", "-dev"]
```

What I'm doing:

```
$ docker build -t hyzhak/vault-dev .

Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.56 kB
Step 0 : FROM centos:centos6
 ---> 72703a0520b7
Step 1 : ENV VAULT_VERSION 0.3.0
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3a7cefb4b4aa
Step 2 : ENV VAULT_SHA256 30b8953e98059d1e8d97f6a164aa574a346a58caf9c5c74a911056f42fbef4d5
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f2279f3a8d9a
Step 3 : RUN yum install -y wget unzip
 ---> Running in bf584ef3432f
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package unzip.x86_64 0:6.0-2.el6_6 will be installed
---> Package wget.x86_64 0:1.12-5.el6_6.1 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package         Arch             Version                  Repository      Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 unzip           x86_64           6.0-2.el6_6              base           149 k
 wget            x86_64           1.12-5.el6_6.1           base           483 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install       2 Package(s)

Total download size: 633 k
Installed size: 2.1 M
Downloading Packages:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                           180 kB/s | 633 kB     00:03
warning: rpmts_HdrFromFdno: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: NOKEY
Retrieving key from file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
Importing GPG key 0xC105B9DE:
 Userid : CentOS-6 Key (CentOS 6 Official Signing Key) <centos-6-key@centos.org>
 Package: centos-release-6-7.el6.centos.12.3.x86_64 (installed)
 From   : /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Transaction Test Succeeded
Running Transaction
  Installing : wget-1.12-5.el6_6.1.x86_64                                   1/2
install-info: No such file or directory for /usr/share/info/wget.info.gz
  Installing : unzip-6.0-2.el6_6.x86_64                                     2/2
  Verifying  : unzip-6.0-2.el6_6.x86_64                                     1/2
  Verifying  : wget-1.12-5.el6_6.1.x86_64                                   2/2

Installed:
  unzip.x86_64 0:6.0-2.el6_6            wget.x86_64 0:1.12-5.el6_6.1

Complete!
 ---> 39319a2a5d82
Removing intermediate container bf584ef3432f
Step 4 : RUN wget http://dl.bintray.com/mitchellh/vault/vault_${VAULT_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip &&  echo "${VAULT_SHA256}  vault_${VAULT_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip" | sha256sum -c - &&  unzip vault_${VAULT_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip &&  rm vault_${VAULT_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip &&  mv vault /usr/bin
 ---> Running in 668009a0a95c
--2015-10-05 09:07:55--  http://dl.bintray.com/mitchellh/vault/vault_0.3.0_linux_amd64.zip
Resolving dl.bintray.com... 5.153.24.114
Connecting to dl.bintray.com|5.153.24.114|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302
Location: http://d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net/b11b4f3d90450515f9930da49953649fe0848057?response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22vault_0.3.0_linux_amd64.zip%22&Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOiBbeyJSZXNvdXJjZSI6Imh0dHAqOi8vZDI5dnprNG93MDd3aTcuY2xvdWRmcm9udC5uZXQvYjExYjRmM2Q5MDQ1MDUxNWY5OTMwZGE0OTk1MzY0OWZlMDg0ODA1Nz9yZXNwb25zZS1jb250ZW50LWRpc3Bvc2l0aW9uPWF0dGFjaG1lbnQlM0JmaWxlbmFtZSUzRCUyMnZhdWx0XzAuMy4wX2xpbnV4X2FtZDY0LnppcCUyMiIsIkNvbmRpdGlvbiI6eyJEYXRlTGVzc1RoYW4iOnsiQVdTOkVwb2NoVGltZSI6MTQ0NDAzNjc5Nn0sIklwQWRkcmVzcyI6eyJBV1M6U291cmNlSXAiOiIwLjAuMC4wLzAifX19XX0_&Signature=bRNeHgbTenO1ZNzZYTxf6iLvZYJS3YKxbHKH-pIdN0-K59Osn5qtWNbyqLHG~MNMp-4l4tW6tgeW6cZIx9c5ZtOcj8-CfQOpCU8hXhJQ48drj2GlU2DRnWJxER8r3cLkJz75ZLK7KJiB2-XUJxfHufmIhhatpxsnxIjJ~EuPkdj0mBdhoa4MaVa9rOzW~aCjCp980YTkzDXgJmIR0DNs8guQZ5F1tqf4SkxWPKiHvFkHOf0KgY6LVQP9pl8M6XNTYszG1bEyZ7gWvINMcs50Ha3mGIwB714HEjadTUTIMKDGy8ZYOFEym8zRxxZieE67DCcmG2IN-UT2iYEyVWfDdA__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIFKFWOMXM2UMTSFA [following]
--2015-10-05 09:07:56--  http://d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net/b11b4f3d90450515f9930da49953649fe0848057?response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22vault_0.3.0_linux_amd64.zip%22&Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOiBbeyJSZXNvdXJjZSI6Imh0dHAqOi8vZDI5dnprNG93MDd3aTcuY2xvdWRmcm9udC5uZXQvYjExYjRmM2Q5MDQ1MDUxNWY5OTMwZGE0OTk1MzY0OWZlMDg0ODA1Nz9yZXNwb25zZS1jb250ZW50LWRpc3Bvc2l0aW9uPWF0dGFjaG1lbnQlM0JmaWxlbmFtZSUzRCUyMnZhdWx0XzAuMy4wX2xpbnV4X2FtZDY0LnppcCUyMiIsIkNvbmRpdGlvbiI6eyJEYXRlTGVzc1RoYW4iOnsiQVdTOkVwb2NoVGltZSI6MTQ0NDAzNjc5Nn0sIklwQWRkcmVzcyI6eyJBV1M6U291cmNlSXAiOiIwLjAuMC4wLzAifX19XX0_&Signature=bRNeHgbTenO1ZNzZYTxf6iLvZYJS3YKxbHKH-pIdN0-K59Osn5qtWNbyqLHG~MNMp-4l4tW6tgeW6cZIx9c5ZtOcj8-CfQOpCU8hXhJQ48drj2GlU2DRnWJxER8r3cLkJz75ZLK7KJiB2-XUJxfHufmIhhatpxsnxIjJ~EuPkdj0mBdhoa4MaVa9rOzW~aCjCp980YTkzDXgJmIR0DNs8guQZ5F1tqf4SkxWPKiHvFkHOf0KgY6LVQP9pl8M6XNTYszG1bEyZ7gWvINMcs50Ha3mGIwB714HEjadTUTIMKDGy8ZYOFEym8zRxxZieE67DCcmG2IN-UT2iYEyVWfDdA__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIFKFWOMXM2UMTSFA
Resolving d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net... 54.239.168.131, 54.239.168.113, 54.239.168.149, ...
Connecting to d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net|54.239.168.131|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 7144775 (6.8M) [application/unknown]
Saving to: `vault_0.3.0_linux_amd64.zip'

     0K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0%  245K 28s
    50K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  1%  536K 20s

  6900K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 99%  897K 0s
  6950K .......... .......... .......                         100%  905K=11s

2015-10-05 09:08:07 (644 KB/s) - `vault_0.3.0_linux_amd64.zip' saved [7144775/7144775]

vault_0.3.0_linux_amd64.zip: OK
Archive:  vault_0.3.0_linux_amd64.zip
  inflating: vault
 ---> 4a7ad17d1c3e
Removing intermediate container 668009a0a95c
Step 5 : ENTRYPOINT vault
 ---> Running in 5d94eea8c63a
 ---> 615ebbc603eb
Removing intermediate container 5d94eea8c63a
Step 6 : CMD server -dev
 ---> Running in 534d6b77a08f
 ---> e4972008c99e
Removing intermediate container 534d6b77a08f
Step 7 : EXPOSE 8200
 ---> Running in cdaeb80c9f6d
 ---> 3d102a6ca778
Removing intermediate container cdaeb80c9f6d
Successfully built 3d102a6ca778
```

check images

```
$ docker images

REPOSITORY                 TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
hyzhak/vault-dev           latest              3d102a6ca778        10 minutes ago      275 MB

start docker
```

run vault docker

```
$ docker run -p 49161:8200 -d hyzhak/vault-dev

31a7925fa08a5483f11a4d307f28813b01c3e4527a6e035c00227ab1aa21df48
```

check whether it work right now

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                      COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
344af48eb05b        hyzhak/vault-dev           "vault server -dev"    25 minutes ago      Up 17 minutes       0.0.0.0:49161->8200/tcp   admiring_brahmagupta
```

check logs

```
$ docker logs admiring_brahmagupta
==> WARNING: Dev mode is enabled!

In this mode, Vault is completely in-memory and unsealed.
Vault is configured to only have a single unseal key. The root
token has already been authenticated with the CLI, so you can
immediately begin using the Vault CLI.

The only step you need to take is to set the following
environment variables:

    export VAULT_ADDR='http://127.0.0.1:8200'

The unseal key and root token are reproduced below in case you
want to seal/unseal the Vault or play with authentication.

Unseal Key: ab8f054f17c20954ab4bb319ebd9547a8e270b23f3cce7ab84a170eba37c1a6d
Root Token: 6ae939f8-0cb0-fcb4-82f4-07fdeef289a7

==> Vault server configuration:

         Log Level: info
             Mlock: supported: true, enabled: false
           Backend: inmem
        Listener 1: tcp (addr: "127.0.0.1:8200", tls: "disabled")

==> Vault server started! Log data will stream in below:

2015/10/05 09:11:53 [INFO] core: security barrier initialized (shares: 1, threshold 1)
2015/10/05 09:11:53 [INFO] core: post-unseal setup starting
2015/10/05 09:11:53 [INFO] core: mounted backend of type generic at logical/19fa5174-70fa-90ed-fa4f-ef08040bbe6e/
2015/10/05 09:11:53 [INFO] core: mounted backend of type cubbyhole at logical/a00018a6-ce98-3df4-28af-955e2f572f8d/
2015/10/05 09:11:53 [INFO] core: mounted backend of type system at sys/
2015/10/05 09:11:53 [INFO] core: post-unseal setup complete
2015/10/05 09:11:53 [INFO] core: root token generated
2015/10/05 09:11:53 [INFO] core: pre-seal teardown starting
2015/10/05 09:11:53 [INFO] rollback: starting rollback manager
2015/10/05 09:11:53 [INFO] rollback: stopping rollback manager
2015/10/05 09:11:53 [INFO] core: pre-seal teardown complete
2015/10/05 09:11:53 [INFO] core: vault is unsealed
2015/10/05 09:11:53 [INFO] core: post-unseal setup starting
2015/10/05 09:11:53 [INFO] core: mounted backend of type generic at logical/19fa5174-70fa-90ed-fa4f-ef08040bbe6e/
2015/10/05 09:11:53 [INFO] core: mounted backend of type cubbyhole at logical/a00018a6-ce98-3df4-28af-955e2f572f8d/
2015/10/05 09:11:53 [INFO] core: mounted backend of type system at sys/
2015/10/05 09:11:53 [INFO] core: post-unseal setup complete
2015/10/05 09:11:53 [INFO] rollback: starting rollback manager
```

works well by CLI

```
$ alias vault='docker exec -it admiring_brahmagupta vault "$@"'
$ vault --version
Vault v0.3.0
```

get ip of docker

```
$ docker-machine ip default
192.168.99.100
```

and try to connect to vault (This one does not work!)

```
$ curl -i http://192.168.99.100:49161/v1/sys/init
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.99.100 port 49161: Connection refused
```

same result for any  in http://192.168.99.100:49161/. In same time Node.js from example https://docs.docker.com/examples/nodejs_web_app/ expose 8080 without any problems. So I have based my docker file on https://docs.docker.com/examples/nodejs_web_app/ but without any luck. Also I have tried ready make docker file https://hub.docker.com/r/voxxit/vault/ and others from a hub. Which gives same result.

Why *Node* expose 8080 without problem, but *Vault* doesn't work? And how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the insecure-by-default nature of "dev" mode in Vault, it binds to loopback (127.0.0.1). You'll have to supply a configuration to listen on `0.0.0.0:8200` instead if you intend to access it from outside of the same network namespace.

See here: https://vaultproject.io/docs/config/index.html

Comment: thanks, interesting that when I was trying to use 0.0.0.0:8200 on bare docker Vault says "Error initializing listener of type tcp: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:8200: bind: address already in use" But with 0.0.0.0:8201 everything works fine. So solution is working great!